# Aligning a 90 degree flipped div with a regular horizontal div

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to put a 90 degree flip a div next to a normal horizontally?

In my example, I want the blue div ("some text") to be vertical and be next to the horizontal "`bottom-right`" div.  Is it possible to do so while making it responsive?  I don't want just the text to be flipped, I want any items I put inside that div to also be flipped.

https://jsfiddle.net/duah6svr/1/

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.big-div{
  width:600px;
  height:600px;
  background:gray;
}
.top{
  float:right;
  height:30%;
  background:red;
  width:80%;
}
.bottom{
  width:100%;
  height:70%;
  background:green;
  float:right;
}
.bottom-right{
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  width:80%;
  background:pink;
}
.vertical-invert{
  width:20%;
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-div">
  <div class="top">
    
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="vertical-invert">SOME TEXT</div>
    <div class="bottom-right"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I think you mean "rotated" rather than "vertically flipped"...right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+rotated+text

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake vertically flipped would mean just upside down, I meant rotated, ill fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flexbox and the `writing-mode` attribute. Here is a [working fiddle demonstrating](https://jsfiddle.net/duah6svr/2/). In case you want to change the text orienation you can use something different for `writin-mode` as described [here](https://www.thecssninja.com/css/real-text-rotation-with-css)

[Updated version](https://jsfiddle.net/duah6svr/7/): Bottom of the text is on the left side. The trick is to set the `writing-mode` to `vertical-lr`

HTML:

```
    <div class="big-div">

  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="vertical-invert">SOME TEXT</div>
    <div class="bottom-right"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.big-div{
  background:gray;
}

.bottom{
  width:100%;
  height:70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.bottom-right{
  width:80%;
  background:pink;
}
.vertical-invert{
  width: 20%;
  background:blue;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Problem with this is I want it flipped the other way, bottom of letters to be face the left side of the horizontal div

Comment: @Snorlax I just added another example. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you for the suggestion, I updated my answer and will do it next time!

Comment: the text's bottom is facing to the left, I want it to be facing to the right

Comment: @Snorlax Sorry - i accidently added the wrong link. Should be working now

Comment: You have the text on the left hand side but I want the bottom of the text to be FACING the right side, so what you have now, the text would be rotated 180, I know how to rotate the text with     -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%); for example. but it doesn't make it responsive